# C++ How do I pass a smart pointer into a output parameter that will modify the pointer

Tags: c++, parameters, output, smart-pointers, xaudio2

All raw pointers need to be handled with Smartpointers in a program.

But I'm having problems with this Xaudio2 call

```
HRESULT XAudio2Create(_Out_  IXAudio2 **ppXAudio2, _In_   UINT32 Flags,
    _In_   XAUDIO2_PROCESSOR XAudio2Processor);
```

My Question is how do you use smart pointers when passing it as a pointer to a pointer and is this even possible? If not how should I go about this in a smart way? I.e how do I pass a smart pointer for the parameter `_Out_  IXAudio2 **ppXAudio2`

Any Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Since it's an *out* parameter, you'd presumably need to wrap it in a smart pointer after `XAudio2Create` returns. You'd need a custom deleter though if there's another function you're supposed to call to release objects that were created this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two wrinkles here--first is to handle the fact that the function expects a raw pointer to a (nonconst!) raw pointer, second is to work around the fact that all the built-in smart pointers call `delete` on the owned pointer when what you need to do here is call its `Release()` method. Waiting to create the smart pointer until after the factory function returns will solve problem 1, and a custom deleter can solve problem 2. Exactly how you want to do things is up to you, but something like this should work:

```
IXAudio2* p = nullptr;
if(!SUCCEEDED(XAudio2Create(&p, GetFlags(), GetProcessor())))
    ; // fail
std::shared_ptr<IXAudio2> smart(p,
   [](IXAudio2* p) { p->Release(); }); // or unique_ptr with somewhat different syntax
```

Addendum: There have been tons of COM smart pointers written over the years that do essentially this and also call `AddRef()`/`RemoveRef()` when appropriate. e.g. ATL's `CComPtr`. If you have access to one of these, you could use it instead of rolling your own.